# tradingview placeholder not working on alert

Tags: pine-script, placeholder

I am having issues displaying the value for the placeholder {{exchange}}:{{ticker}}

When I create the alert based on an indicator alertcondition it does not work and I see "{{exchange}}:{{ticker}}" on the alert.

However when the alert is created based on the crossover of a value for the chart it does replace the ticker.

The code of the indicator for this alert is:

```
alertcondition(Longtrigger, title="Long Alert", message="Long")
```

Then I set the alert message to

```
{ "time": "{{time}}", "Action": "LONG", "pair": "{{exchange}}:{{ticker}}", "Timeframe": "12h" }
```

**UPDATED**
I might have figured it out. The version of the script was 3, when I modify to 4 it works during test. I will keep an eye when on production.